# How to achieve hierarchical navigation using Navigation framework?

Tags: android, navigation

I'm using Android's new [navigation framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) in my app, and I have some trouble in hierarchical navigation.

## Background

My app has a bottom navigation view with three destinations, and for the first destination, there is a tab layout with three tabs.

So in my main activity's layout, there is a `BottomNavigationView` in the bottom, and above should be a navigation host fragment containing three main destinations `A`, `B` and `C` (and I used the [NavigationAdvancedSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) to achieve this, which includes three navigation graphs). For fragment `A`'s layout, there should be a `TabLayout` in the top, and below should also be a navigation host fragment containing three sub destination `A1`, `A2`, `A3`.

## Problems

Apparently, the thing below the `TabLayout` in `A` should not be a navigation host fragment, since `A` itself is already in the main navigation host fragment.

However, `A1`, `A2`, `A3` should also not be in the main navigation graph, since the main navigation graph takes the whole area above the bottom navigation view in main activity's layout, and `A1`, `A2`, `A3` should take the area between the tab layout in `A` and bottom navigation view in main activity.

Moreover, maybe nested navigation graph is also inappropriate, because the nested navigation graph doesn't allow multiple entry points, and for example, if user now at `A`'s second tab `A2`, and then switches to `B`, I want user to be able to see `A2` if he re-switches to `A`.

Comment: `Apparently, the thing below the TabLayout in A should not be a navigation host fragment, since A itself is already in the main navigation host fragment.` - nested nav hosts are certainly supported. Why would you think it isn't? You wouldn't use a `NavHostFragment` for a `ViewPager` / `ViewPager2` like you'd pair with tabs though.

Comment: @ianhanniballake There is few tutorial about nested nav hosts... I wonder how to deal with back button when using nested nav host, which one should be set `defaultNavHost`?

Comment: You'd make both the `defaultNavHost` as they are both the default for their respective levels of the Fragment hierarchy.